# Can’t find Active Directory after installing it on the Server 2019

Tags: server, active-directory, windows-server-2019, servermanager

I installed AD step-by step as required [PS query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Sue0.png), but in result can’t find it anywhere. I can only access that through Powershell by commands.

The exact problem is that there are no such option in Server Manager > Tools > Active Directory Users and Computers like on that photo [What I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcFJ8.png)

I see only PS module available. But it should be like that:

[How should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGbJc.png)

Can someone give an advise how I can find GUI version of this? Write me if you need additional info.
Thanks!

I was trying to reinstall this by different guides. I added DNS server too, but the problem still persists

Comment: Installing the requisite role services is not enough - you need to configure the ADDS deployment as well. Either run `Install-ADDSDomainController` in PowerShell on the machine, or use Server Manager to complete to DC promotion process. First time you launch Server Manager after completing the ADDS role install, there'll be a notification in the top right corner prompting you to complete the process

Comment: Thanks Mathias. The domain controller was already installed, after some errors it somehow works        ¯\_(ツ)_/¯